# Chromium-based applications crashing after recent Fedora upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, brave

After a recent `dnf upgrade` on my Fedora 34 system, I'm no longer
able to run either google-chrome or brave-browser. Both fail with:

```
GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
```

Brave additionally says:

```
ERROR:profile_attributes_storage.cc(547)] Failed to PNG encode the image.
```

I haven't run into anything else that shows the same symptoms (e.g.,
Firefox runs fine). I am using the Nvidia kernel modules:

```
# lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             69632  10
nvidia_modeset       1200128  20 nvidia_drm
nvidia              35315712  987 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        290816  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   630784  16 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm,i915
```

...but everything was working just fine before the upgrade.

The problem doesn't seem to be kernel related; I've rebooted into the
two previous kernels and the problem persists. I've tried downgrading
Brave to a previous release and that didn't seem to help, either.

To make sure it isn't some local setting, I created a new user account and tried the browsers there; they seem to crash the same way.

Browsing through the list of packages that were upgraded (below) I don't
see anything that jumps out as an obvious suspect. Does this sound at
all familiar to anybody?

This is the list of packages that were updated during the `dnf upgrade` process:

```
Install       kernel-5.13.10-200.fc34.x86_64                               @updates
Install       kernel-core-5.13.10-200.fc34.x86_64                          @updates
Install       kernel-devel-5.13.10-200.fc34.x86_64                         @updates
Install       kernel-modules-5.13.10-200.fc34.x86_64                       @updates
Install       kernel-modules-extra-5.13.10-200.fc34.x86_64                 @updates
Upgrade       python3-qgis-3.20.2-1.fc34.x86_64                            @copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dani:qgis
Upgrade       qgis-3.20.2-1.fc34.x86_64                                    @copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dani:qgis
Upgrade       qgis-grass-3.20.2-1.fc34.x86_64                              @copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dani:qgis
Upgrade       ModemManager-1.16.8-4.fc34.x86_64                            @updates
Upgrade       ModemManager-glib-1.16.8-4.fc34.x86_64                       @updates
Upgrade       autocorr-en-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.noarch                          @updates
Upgrade       blivet-gui-runtime-2.3.0-1.fc34.noarch                       @updates
Upgrade       c-ares-1.17.2-1.fc34.x86_64                                  @updates
Upgrade       crun-0.21-1.fc34.x86_64                                      @updates
Upgrade       emacs-filesystem-1:27.2-5.fc34.noarch                        @updates
Upgrade       eog-40.3-1.fc34.x86_64                                       @updates
Upgrade       evolution-data-server-3.40.4-1.fc34.x86_64                   @updates
Upgrade       evolution-data-server-langpacks-3.40.4-1.fc34.noarch         @updates
Upgrade       fedora-release-common-34-36.noarch                           @updates
Upgrade       fedora-release-identity-workstation-34-36.noarch             @updates
Upgrade       fedora-release-workstation-34-36.noarch                      @updates
Upgrade       firefox-91.0-1.fc34.x86_64                                   @updates
Upgrade       fuse-overlayfs-1.7.1-1.fc34.x86_64                           @updates
Upgrade       gjs-1.68.3-1.fc34.x86_64                                     @updates
Upgrade       glib-networking-2.68.2-1.fc34.x86_64                         @updates
Upgrade       gnome-initial-setup-40.4-1.fc34.x86_64                       @updates
Upgrade       gnome-maps-40.4-1.fc34.x86_64                                @updates
Upgrade       gnome-software-40.4-1.fc34.x86_64                            @updates
Upgrade       gnome-user-docs-40.4-1.fc34.noarch                           @updates
Upgrade       gutenprint-5.3.4-4.fc34.x86_64                               @updates
Upgrade       gutenprint-cups-5.3.4-4.fc34.x86_64                          @updates
Upgrade       gutenprint-libs-5.3.4-4.fc34.x86_64                          @updates
Upgrade       hivex-1.3.21-1.fc34.x86_64                                   @updates
Upgrade       ibus-typing-booster-2.14.0-1.fc34.noarch                     @updates
Upgrade       libepoxy-1.5.9-1.fc34.x86_64                                 @updates
Upgrade       libgexiv2-0.12.3-1.fc34.x86_64                               @updates
Upgrade       libinput-1.18.1-1.fc34.x86_64                                @updates
Upgrade       libipa_hbac-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                              @updates
Upgrade       libmbim-1.26.0-1.fc34.x86_64                                 @updates
Upgrade       libmbim-utils-1.26.0-1.fc34.x86_64                           @updates
Upgrade       libpwquality-1.4.4-6.fc34.x86_64                             @updates
Upgrade       libqmi-1.28.8-1.fc34.x86_64                                  @updates
Upgrade       libqmi-utils-1.28.8-1.fc34.x86_64                            @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-calc-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                     @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-core-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                     @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-data-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.noarch                     @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-emailmerge-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64               @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-filters-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                  @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-graphicfilter-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64            @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-gtk3-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                     @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-help-en-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                  @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-impress-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                  @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-langpack-en-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64              @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-ogltrans-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                 @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-opensymbol-fonts-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.noarch         @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-pdfimport-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-pyuno-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                    @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-ure-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                      @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-ure-common-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.noarch               @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-writer-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                   @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-x11-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64                      @updates
Upgrade       libreoffice-xsltfilter-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64               @updates
Upgrade       libsndfile-1.0.31-5.fc34.fc34.i686                           @updates
Upgrade       libsndfile-1.0.31-5.fc34.fc34.x86_64                         @updates
Upgrade       libsss_autofs-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                            @updates
Upgrade       libsss_certmap-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                           @updates
Upgrade       libsss_idmap-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                             @updates
Upgrade       libsss_nss_idmap-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                         @updates
Upgrade       libsss_sudo-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                              @updates
Upgrade       libtpms-0.8.4-2.20210624gita594c4692a.fc34.0.x86_64          @updates
Upgrade       libwebp-1.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64                                  @updates
Upgrade       m17n-db-1.8.0-20.fc34.noarch                                 @updates
Upgrade       minizip-3.0.2-4.fc34.x86_64                                  @updates
Upgrade       mobile-broadband-provider-info-20210805-1.fc34.noarch        @updates
Upgrade       mock-core-configs-35-1.fc34.noarch                           @updates
Upgrade       mozjs78-78.13.0-1.fc34.x86_64                                @updates
Upgrade       mt32emu-2.5.3-1.fc34.x86_64                                  @updates
Upgrade       mtools-4.0.35-1.fc34.x86_64                                  @updates
Upgrade       osinfo-db-20210809-1.fc34.noarch                             @updates
Upgrade       perl-Text-Tabs+Wrap-2021.0726-1.fc34.noarch                  @updates
Upgrade       python3-enchant-3.2.1-1.fc34.noarch                          @updates
Upgrade       python3-pwquality-1.4.4-6.fc34.x86_64                        @updates
Upgrade       python3-unbound-1.13.2-1.fc34.x86_64                         @updates
Upgrade       qt5-qtdeclarative-5.15.2-7.fc34.x86_64                       @updates
Upgrade       s3fs-fuse-1.90-1.fc34.x86_64                                 @updates
Upgrade       selinux-policy-34.16-1.fc34.noarch                           @updates
Upgrade       selinux-policy-targeted-34.16-1.fc34.noarch                  @updates
Upgrade       shadow-utils-2:4.8.1-9.fc34.x86_64                           @updates
Upgrade       skopeo-1:1.4.0-2.fc34.x86_64                                 @updates
Upgrade       sssd-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                                     @updates
Upgrade       sssd-ad-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                                  @updates
Upgrade       sssd-client-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                              @updates
Upgrade       sssd-common-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                              @updates
Upgrade       sssd-common-pac-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                          @updates
Upgrade       sssd-ipa-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                                 @updates
Upgrade       sssd-kcm-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                                 @updates
Upgrade       sssd-krb5-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                                @updates
Upgrade       sssd-krb5-common-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                         @updates
Upgrade       sssd-ldap-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                                @updates
Upgrade       sssd-nfs-idmap-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                           @updates
Upgrade       sssd-proxy-2.5.2-2.fc34.x86_64                               @updates
Upgrade       svt-av1-libs-0.8.7-2.fc34.x86_64                             @updates
Upgrade       unbound-libs-1.13.2-1.fc34.x86_64                            @updates
Upgrade       usbredir-0.11.0-1.fc34.x86_64                                @updates
Upgrade       vim-common-2:8.2.3354-1.fc34.x86_64                          @updates
Upgrade       vim-filesystem-2:8.2.3354-1.fc34.noarch                      @updates
Upgrade       vim-minimal-2:8.2.3354-1.fc34.x86_64                         @updates
Upgrade       virtualbox-guest-additions-6.1.26-1.fc34.x86_64              @updates
Upgrade       google-chrome-stable-92.0.4515.159-1.x86_64                  @google-chrome
```

**Update**

Recent updates to Brave and Chrome seemed to solve this particular
problem, although other Chromium-based apps are still failing:

- Chromium itself (chromium-91.0.4472.164-1.fc34.x86_64) fails
- Slack ( slack-4.19.2-0.1.fc21.x86_64) fails
- Chromium 93.0.4577.63-1.fc34.x86_64 seems to work

Running `chromium-browser` from 91.0.4472 with `--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer`, as suggested variously online if you
look for the `GPU process exited unexpectedly` error, does not solve
the problem.

The backtrace from Chromium looks like this:

```
[606558:606576:0907/073125.107865:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[606558:606576:0907/073125.425012:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[606558:606576:0907/073125.738604:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[606903:606903:0907/073125.748883:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[606558:606576:0907/073125.945651:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[606997:606997:0907/073125.952810:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[606558:606576:0907/073126.158012:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[607029:607029:0907/073126.164402:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[606558:606576:0907/073126.364238:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[607107:607107:0907/073126.367075:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[606558:606576:0907/073126.542684:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[607145:607145:0907/073126.545507:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[606558:606576:0907/073126.725641:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[607224:607224:0907/073126.728459:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
[606558:606576:0907/073126.904228:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=159
[606558:606576:0907/073126.904250:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
#0 0x55fe6b1b4279 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x55fe6b116046 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x55fe6b128d44 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#3 0x55fe68c8a870 content::(anonymous namespace)::IntentionallyCrashBrowserForUnusableGpuProcess()
#4 0x55fe68c8ad59 content::GpuDataManagerImplPrivate::FallBackToNextGpuMode()
#5 0x55fe68c84cb3 content::GpuDataManagerImpl::FallBackToNextGpuMode()
#6 0x55fe68c97828 content::GpuProcessHost::OnProcessCrashed()
#7 0x55fe68a8cb78 content::BrowserChildProcessHostImpl::OnChildDisconnected()
#8 0x55fe6baa3fcb mojo::InterfaceEndpointClient::NotifyError()
#9 0x55fe6c1113dc IPC::(anonymous namespace)::ChannelAssociatedGroupController::NotifyEndpointOfError()
#10 0x55fe6c117014 IPC::(anonymous namespace)::ChannelAssociatedGroupController::OnPipeError()
#11 0x55fe6baa2750 mojo::Connector::HandleError()
#12 0x55fe6bac688f mojo::SimpleWatcher::OnHandleReady()
#13 0x55fe6bac6dbb mojo::SimpleWatcher::Context::CallNotify()
#14 0x55fe69301c77 mojo::core::WatcherDispatcher::InvokeWatchCallback()
#15 0x55fe693011b3 mojo::core::Watch::InvokeCallback()
#16 0x55fe692fd9d8 mojo::core::RequestContext::~RequestContext()
#17 0x55fe692f083a mojo::core::NodeChannel::OnChannelError()
#18 0x55fe693064ef mojo::core::ChannelPosix::OnFileCanReadWithoutBlocking()
#19 0x55fe6b1e1443 base::MessagePumpLibevent::OnLibeventNotification()
#20 0x55fe6b33dd2d event_base_loop
#21 0x55fe6b1e0edd base::MessagePumpLibevent::Run()
#22 0x55fe6b18d530 base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::Run()
#23 0x55fe6b15ba59 base::RunLoop::Run()
#24 0x55fe6b19da59 base::Thread::Run()
#25 0x55fe68abeafa content::BrowserProcessSubThread::IOThreadRun()
#26 0x55fe6b19e768 base::Thread::ThreadMain()
#27 0x55fe6b1c6aa6 base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc()
#28 0x7f58f7855aaf start_thread
#29 0x7f58f78da300 __clone3

Received signal 6
#0 0x55fe6b1b4279 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x55fe6b116046 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x55fe6b1b3cf5 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
#3 0x7f58f780a760 (/usr/lib64/libc.so.6+0x4275f)
#4 0x7f58f7857783 __GI___pthread_kill
#5 0x7f58f780a6b6 __GI_raise
#6 0x7f58f77f47d3 __GI_abort
#7 0x55fe6b1b37b5 base::debug::BreakDebugger()
#8 0x55fe6b129615 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#9 0x55fe68c8a870 content::(anonymous namespace)::IntentionallyCrashBrowserForUnusableGpuProcess()
#10 0x55fe68c8ad59 content::GpuDataManagerImplPrivate::FallBackToNextGpuMode()
#11 0x55fe68c84cb3 content::GpuDataManagerImpl::FallBackToNextGpuMode()
#12 0x55fe68c97828 content::GpuProcessHost::OnProcessCrashed()
#13 0x55fe68a8cb78 content::BrowserChildProcessHostImpl::OnChildDisconnected()
#14 0x55fe6baa3fcb mojo::InterfaceEndpointClient::NotifyError()
#15 0x55fe6c1113dc IPC::(anonymous namespace)::ChannelAssociatedGroupController::NotifyEndpointOfError()
#16 0x55fe6c117014 IPC::(anonymous namespace)::ChannelAssociatedGroupController::OnPipeError()
#17 0x55fe6baa2750 mojo::Connector::HandleError()
#18 0x55fe6bac688f mojo::SimpleWatcher::OnHandleReady()
#19 0x55fe6bac6dbb mojo::SimpleWatcher::Context::CallNotify()
#20 0x55fe69301c77 mojo::core::WatcherDispatcher::InvokeWatchCallback()
#21 0x55fe693011b3 mojo::core::Watch::InvokeCallback()
#22 0x55fe692fd9d8 mojo::core::RequestContext::~RequestContext()
#23 0x55fe692f083a mojo::core::NodeChannel::OnChannelError()
#24 0x55fe693064ef mojo::core::ChannelPosix::OnFileCanReadWithoutBlocking()
#25 0x55fe6b1e1443 base::MessagePumpLibevent::OnLibeventNotification()
#26 0x55fe6b33dd2d event_base_loop
#27 0x55fe6b1e0edd base::MessagePumpLibevent::Run()
#28 0x55fe6b18d530 base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::Run()
#29 0x55fe6b15ba59 base::RunLoop::Run()
#30 0x55fe6b19da59 base::Thread::Run()
#31 0x55fe68abeafa content::BrowserProcessSubThread::IOThreadRun()
#32 0x55fe6b19e768 base::Thread::ThreadMain()
#33 0x55fe6b1c6aa6 base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc()
#34 0x7f58f7855aaf start_thread
#35 0x7f58f78da300 __clone3
  r8: 00007f58e3e60ed0  r9: 000013c3cf38e820 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000202
 r12: 0000000000000006 r13: 00007f58e3e62100 r14: 00007f58e3e620c0 r15: 000013c3cee3afc0
  di: 000000000009415e  si: 0000000000094170  bp: 0000000000094170  bx: 00007f58e3e64640
  dx: 0000000000000006  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f58f7857783  sp: 00007f58e3e60ea0
  ip: 00007f58f7857783 efl: 0000000000000202 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

Comment: Chrome and Firefox were both upgraded. As a test can you confirm if Firefox is crashing or functional?

Comment: Firefox is functioning. This appears to only affect Chrome-based browsers, but downgrading Brave didn't change the behavior.

Comment: Are you able to try a new Chrome/Brave user profile?  Trying to determine if the crashing is linked to hardware acceleration. My hope is that a new user profile, by default, would have it disabled.

Comment: I tried it from a completely fresh *user account* -- no existing browser profiles (or any other files), and the browsers still crashed.

Comment: Well that tells us, the problem is either hardware acceleration (due to it being enabled by default), or it has nothing to do with hardware acceleration and has something to do with unique to Brave and Chrome. [Failed to PNG encode the image.](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/13762) appears to have something to do with the switching profile avatars.  [This](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/issues/1124) suggests using the `disable-gpu`  flag might help

Comment: On Manjaro I solved a similar issue today by installing `libva-nvidia-driver` which removed `libva-vdpau-driver`. Chromium, Signal and others finally work again.